# Is there a way to force multiple Context Consumers to share state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using the React Context API with the main intent of avoiding prop drilling. Right now my Context includes a `useState` and various functions that update the state - these are put into a const object that is passed as the `value` prop of `ActionsContext.Provider`. This is an abstraction of my current component hierarchy:

```
Header
---NavPanel
ContentContainer
---Content (Context.Consumer being returned in this component)
```

where Header and ContentContainer are sibling elements and NavPanel and ContentContainer are their respective children.

I initially put the `Context.Consumer` in Content because the other elements did not need it. However I'm building a feature now where NavPanel needs to know about the state that's managed by the Context. So I put another Consumer in NavPanel, only to find that a separate Consumer means a separate instance of the state.

Is there any smart workaround that gives NavPanel and Content access to the same state, that doesn't involve putting the Consumer in the parent component of Header and Content? That would result in a lot of prop drilling with the way my app is currently structured.

Codesandbox example of multiple instances: https://codesandbox.io/s/context-multiple-consumers-v2wte

Comment: Depends on the feature, try adding an example of what you trying to do and what is the best approach to it

Comment: I think it makes more sense to move the context higher up.  One of the things of using context is that it helps avoid prop drilling.
I used a custom hook to easily consume context in both of the components that need it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/context-multiple-consumers-d67cg

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- You should have only one provider for every state you want to share.

```
      <ContextProvider>
        <PartOne />
        <hr />
        <PartTwo />
      </ContextProvider>
```

- It is better to split your context in several contexts so you pass values instead of objects. This way when you update your state React will detect it is different instead of comparing the same object.
- Your input should be a controlled component https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
- Consider using the useContext API for better ergonomics if you are using React 16.8 instead of ContextConsumer.

With these changes, your code would be:

**MyContext.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export const MyItemContext = React.createContext();
export const MySetItemContext = React.createContext();
export const MyHandleKeyContext = React.createContext();

const ContextProvider = props => {
  const [itemBeingEdited, setItemBeingEdited] = useState("");
  const handleKey = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setItemBeingEdited("skittles");
    } else if (event.key === "K") {
      setItemBeingEdited("kilimanjaro");
    } else {
      setItemBeingEdited("");
    }
  };
  const editFunctions = {
    itemBeingEdited,
    setItemBeingEdited,
    handleKey
  };

  return (
    <MyItemContext.Provider value={itemBeingEdited}>
      <MyHandleKeyContext.Provider value={handleKey}>
        <MySetItemContext.Provider value={setItemBeingEdited}>
          {props.children}
        </MySetItemContext.Provider>
      </MyHandleKeyContext.Provider>
    </MyItemContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

**PartOne.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ContextProvider, {
  MyContext,
  MyItemContext,
  MySetItemContext,
  MyHandleKeyContext
} from "./MyContext";
const PartOne = () => {
  // blah
  const itemBeingEdited = useContext(MyItemContext);
  const handleKey = useContext(MyHandleKeyContext);
  const setItem = useContext(MySetItemContext);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{itemBeingEdited}</span>
      <input
        placeholder="Type in me"
        onKeyDown={handleKey}
        value={itemBeingEdited}
        onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PartOne;
```

**PartTwo.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ContextProvider, {
  MyContext,
  MyItemContext,
  MySetItemContext,
  MyHandleKeyContext
} from "./MyContext";
const PartTwo = () => {
  // blah

  const itemBeingEdited = useContext(MyItemContext);
  const handleKey = useContext(MyHandleKeyContext);
  const setItem = useContext(MySetItemContext);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{itemBeingEdited}</span>
      <input
        value={itemBeingEdited}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type in me"
        onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={handleKey}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PartTwo;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PartOne from "./PartOne";
import PartTwo from "./PartTwo";
import ContextProvider from "./MyContext";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <ContextProvider>
        <PartOne />
        <hr />
        <PartTwo />
      </ContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**CodeSandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/context-multiple-consumers-vb9oj?fontsize=14